# Recuperar el valor de checkbox con php

Tags: php, checkbox

En la base de datos tengo la columna `Active` tipo `tinyint(1)`

En el formulario

```
<input type="checkbox" id="proActive" name="proActive" checked value="1">
```

Lo envío por método `POST` y lo recibo...

```
$active = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'proActive', FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN);
```

En teoria el valor de `$active` seria `0` o `1`, pero solo toma el valor de `1` cuando esta `checked` pero si no se chequea `proActive` llega como no signado.

Lo he hecho de esta manera...

```
if (!isset($_POST['proActive'])) 
$active = 0;
```

y funciona, la pregunta es

¿Existe en `PHP` alguna condicional como `if (condicion, valorVerdadero, ValorFalso)` de manera que sea mas practico? Pues tengo `24 checkbox`  en el formulario.

Gracias por su ayuda

Answer (score 1):

Primero yo agruparía todos los checkboxes en un array para pasarlos todos de golpe por post.

Luego puedes utilizar el bucle `foreach ($_POST['checkboxes'] as $value)` para recorrer las 24 opciones y guardar los valores en un array.

Podría quedarte de tal manera:

```
$active = []; 

foreach ($_POST['checkboxes'] as $opcion) {
   if ($option) {
      $active[$opcion] = 1;
   }else{
      $active[$opcion] = 0;
   }
 }
```

Luego solo tendrías que recorrer el array y actualizar los valores en la base de datos.

Comment: Buena opción, Gracias gcc32

Answer (score 0):

El problema surge debido a que cuando el un `input` tipo `checkbox` no esta `checked`, directamente no se envía este valor, lo que provoca el error que mencionas.

Dado que [`filter_input`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.filter-input.php) devuelve:

> En caso de éxito, valor de la variable pedida, `FALSE` si el filtro falla o `NULL` si la variable `variable_name` no está definida. Si se usa el flag `FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE`, retorna `FALSE` si la variable no está definida y `NULL` si el filtro falla.

Una solución, como bien dice la documentación, es usar el flag `FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE`.

#### Ejemplo:

```
$active = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'proActive', FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN, FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE);
```

---

Por otro lado, deberías considerar que **si el filtro falla devolverá `NULL`**, por lo que si quisieras evitar además analizar este otro caso, entonces podrías forzar el resultado a [`boolean` mediante casteo](http://php.net/manual/es/language.types.boolean.php)

#### Ejemplo:

```
$active = (bool) filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'proActive', FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN);
```

---

Por último, existe [el operador ternario](http://php.net/manual/es/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) con el cual puedes hacer escribir la comprobación siguiendo la lógica que planeas.

#### Ejemplo:

```
$active = $_POST['proActive'] == 1 ? true : false;
```

Comment: El operador ternario es la solución! Gracias Marcos